# Derivative of sequence of measures

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, distribution-theory, optimal-transport

Let $\mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})$ be the space of probability measures with finite second moment on $\mathbb{R}$, and $(\mu_t)_{t\geq 0}\subseteq \mathcal{P}_2(\mathbb{R})^{\mathbb{R}^{\geq0 }}$ be a sequence of measures. I am interested in defining a time derivative $\partial_t \mu_t$.

[This](https://adil-salim.github.io/Research/tuto_icml.pdf) tutorial indicates that if there exists a sequence $(v_t)_{t\geq 0}\subseteq L_2(\mu_t)_{t\geq 0}$ such that for each $t$ and $\varphi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ we have
$$\frac{d}{dt} \int \varphi d\mu_t=  \langle \nabla\varphi, v_t\rangle_{\mu_t},$$
then $v_t$ is a velocity field of $\mu_t$, and in some sense is the definition of $\partial_t \mu_t$.

In my opinion, the most natural definition of $\partial_t\mu_t$ would be defined by
$$\partial_t \mu_t=\lim_{\delta\to 0} \frac{\mu_{t+\delta}-\mu_t}{h},$$
so that $\partial_t \mu_t$ is a signed measure with zero total mass. Is this in some sense equivalent to the velocity field $(v_t)_{t\geq 0}$ above? Or is this there a reason why this quantity does not seem to be used in literature?

Comment: You need a metric to talk about limits. Which one you choose?

Comment: @Tobsn I am thinking the total variation metric, as the set of signed measures are a vector space under a norm which induces this metric.

Comment: Your tutorial however works with the Wasserstein geometry, which ich more like an infinite dimensional manifold-like setting. It's not clear how your notion of derivative (which might be interesting in its own right) would be compatible with that, I guess.

Comment: Btw, should be careful with these notes. At least the Wasserstein gradient flow part contains errors.